# How to use a GridLayout in combination with exposing data property

Tags: qt, layout, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am trying to wrap GridLayout inside an Item and exposing the GridLayout's data property as the default property of the item. But this results in two problems.

1. I get a crash when exiting the application.

   - This may in fact be a bug in Qt itself and it might also already been fixed, if not I will report it after fixing 2. I am only able to test on Windows 7 using Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2015 32.bit at the moment.
2. How to use the attached Layout property? Take look in the following example, which results in the error:

   ```
   Non-existent attached object
   ```

on line

```
"Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom | Qt.AlignRight".
```

Example:

```
//MyCustomLayout.qml
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    default property alias data: layout.data

    //Some other QML components not to be within GridView here.

    GridLayout {
        id: layout
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    //Some other QML components not to be within GridView here.

}

//main.qml
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    height: 1024
    width: 768

    MyCustomLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignBottom | Qt.AlignRight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are encountering a bug in Qt, you will want to try updating your Qt version with `MaintenanceTool.exe` that is in your root Qt install directory first and see if it still manifests.  Duplicate bug reports for fixed bugs suck.

Comment: @RossRogers: Thank you for the comment and I agree with you. 1) Was just additional information in case it would help, even though I think it is a bug, fixed or not in a new release.